# Can I show empty field value instead of hiding entire row when one condition is not met in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I hope I am articulate enough in explaining my problem.

What I want is that if one of my AND condition of table1.id = table4.id is not met, I still wanna show the row but I wanna show the table4.field as "No Value" in the result.

Hence if I have a SQL Query:-

```
SELECT table1.field, table2.field, table3.field, table4.field
FROM table1, table2, table3, table4
WHERE table1.id = table2.id AND table2.id = table3.id AND table1.id = table4.id
```

Now only for table1.id = table4.id condition, I want this to be not assertive. If this ID is met, then great, but if not then don't hide the row, but do show the row (and other fields), only show "No Value" for table4.field.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `left join`

also use explicit join syntax

```
SELECT table1.field, table2.field, table3.field, IFNULL(table4.field, 'No Value')
FROM table1
JOIN table2  
ON table1.id = table2.id
JOIN table3
ON table2.id = table3.id
LEFT JOIN table4
ON table1.id = table4.id
```

EDIT:

as per your table structure

```
SELECT
 IFNULL(f.field_full_name_value, 'No Value'), u.name, u.uid, n.title, n.nid, a.timestamp, d.field_video_duration_value AS duration
FROM
db_node_view_count a
join db_node n
ON a.nid = n.nid
JOIN db_field_data_field_video_duration d
ON n.nid = d.entity_id
JOIN db_users u
ON a.uid = u.uid
AND u.uid <> 1
LEFT JOIN db_field_data_field_full_name f 
ON u.uid = f.entity_id
ORDER BY u.uid desc
```

Comment: Hi Radar, Thanks a lot. I tried using it on my query but unfortunately, I am unable to. Would you be so kind to take a look? I added it in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Radar, Is there some error near `a.nid = n.nid JOIN db_field_data_field_video_duration d ON n.nid = d.entity_id`

Comment: @Steve, last one need to be on , try now

Comment: Thank you so much Radar. Now on to understanding it :)

Comment: Radar, can I ask a question. If I want to extend the query you created to show roles of a db_users u. How would I proceed? There is a db_users_roles, which contain all role names with a primary key `rid`. Then the second table is db_users_roles, which contains a matching `uid` and `rid` to show which user selected which role. So what I did was that under `ON a.uid = u.uid`, I added `JOIN db_users_roles ur
ON u.uid = ur.uid
JOIN db_role r
ON ur.rid = r.rid`. It works fine but it shows duplicate rows. Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: @Steve, the user might be having many roles, so you might be shown duplicate rows, only role name might be different